# Need Clarification in Code Efficiency

Tags: optimization, performance

This is my code;

```
  int arr[10]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}; 
  // I need to do some operation using arr[i] if i!=2
```

**a.**

```
  for( int i =0;i<10;i++)
  {
      if(i!=2)
          do some work using arr[i];
  }
```

**b.**

```
  for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
  {
      do some work using arr[i]; 
  }

  undo the work done for arr[2];
```

**a** & **b** are the two ways to achieve the same work. I don't know which is good to do in terms of execution speed and writing style..

Can you please help me in this,,.

Comment: which technology are you using?

Comment: @Gerrie does it really matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always, it depends.

If "do some work" spends a significant amount of time compared to the loop execution itself, go with option a).

If "do some work" is very trivial like adding 1, option b) should be faster because the loop runs uniformly without conditionals and so is more pipeline-friendly.

A third option would be reorder the array before the loop (so the "work"-indices are contiguous) and undo the reordering afterwards. That way could have the advantages of both options.

Fourth: Perhaps the the compiler does some optimization for you anyway. For example it could split the loop in two loops, one for the elements less than 2 and the second for the elements greater than 2.

The relative advantage of the options also depends the architecture your code runs on. If the choice is non-obvious and the performance difference **really** matters, you will have to measure the options and choose the better one.

Answer (score 1):

Of the two options you provide, I would prefer a). A if-sentence does not cost much (it depends on your `SomeWork` execution time, of cause). And b) would only work if the operation can be undone.

Instead you could do this:

```
SomeWork(arr[0]);  // Could be made to an loop from 0 to j
SomeWork(arr[1]);  // if it should work for general purposes

for (int i = 3; i < 10; i++)
    SomeWork(arr[i]);
```

this would be efficient at least :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you would ever want to go through a whole for loop and then go back and undo a subset of the for loop.

In option A, you are iterating an operation and checking a conditional to determine if the operation should be performed. This check is going to have less overhead that performing whatever operation you perform unnecessarily. So in option B, you've done unnecessary work, which you have to go back and undo, and you still have to check your conditional, only in the undo portion instead of the do portion. With the undo, you are adding the opportunities for introducing bugs in your code, plus your essentially performing your whole function 11 times (10 do's and 1 undo) instead of 9 times in option A.

Option 'a' is the obvious choice here, skip the operation for values matching your conditional.

Answer (score 1):

Well what you're doing there is generally known as a for-if antipattern (actually the textbook example for it), which can be easily solved by just splitting the loop into two or more parts, which will be the most efficient solution anyway.

What is more efficient of your two proposed solutions depends mostly on the CPU it is executed on and how much work the undoing is. x86 has an extremely good branch prediction unit, while other CPUs (e.g. older ARM) have none at all, so you may get a few stalled cycles on every loop iteration depending on the created code. So everyone coming up with a general solution here makes generalizations :)

Answer (score 0):

- a) one comparison, no work
- b) work, then more work to undo the original work.

I'd go with a.